# As an Indian, can I work part time in Italy on a Schengen study visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, italy, schengen-visas, study, work

As the title says, I will be travelling to Italy for ~80 days for a self-sustained training course. Can I work part time during this course? I have applied for a schengen study visa. also, does a Italian national short stay study visa allow it?